# How do I resolve circular dependencies in mappings?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hbm

I have 2 tables that have a circular dependency. A `Title` has `Element`s, and in turn each `Element` points to the next `Title` in the path.

However, when I call `BuildSessionFactory()` on my instance of `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration` I receive the following exception:

> An association from the table Element refers to an unmapped class:
>   ElementDAO

I believe this is a result of circular dependencies (it can't map Title first because it refers to Element, and it can't map Element without knowing Title).

**Question:**
How do I combine two mappings in order to resolve circular dependencies?

*Relevant Data (and code snippets) follows:*

**Title**

- Id (Primary Key)
- Name

**Element**

- id_Title (Foreign Key)
- Name
- id_Title_Child (Foreign Key)

**They represent a data structure like so:**
[image: Graph showing relationship of tables]

**My code:**

TitleDAO:

```
public class TitleDAO{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ElementDAO> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

TitleDAO Mapping:

```
<class name="TitleDAO" table="Title" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"/>
    <set name="Elements" table="Element" lazy="true">
      <key column="id_Title"/>
      <many-to-many class="ElementDAO"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

ElementDAO:

```
public class ElementDAO{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual TitleDAO Child { get; set; }
}
```

ElementDAO Mapping:

```
<class name="ElementDAO" table="Element" lazy="true">   
    <property name="Name"/>
    <many-to-one name="Child" class="TitleDAO" column="id_Title_Child"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your model, you have a one-to-many relationship from Title to Element but it is mapped as many-to-many. Change it to:

```
<class name="TitleDAO" table="Title" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"/>
    <set name="Elements" table="Element" lazy="true">
      <key column="id_Title"/>
      <!-- change this to one-to-many -->
      <one-to-many class="ElementDAO"/>
    </set>
</class>
```